# Two FOR statements coupled into one

Tags: matlab

Is is possible to put two for statements into one statement. Something like

```
A = [ 0   0   0   5
      0   2   0   0
      1   3   0   0
      0   0   4   0];
  a=size(A);
  b=size(A);
  ind=0;
  c=0;
  for ({i=1:a},{j=1:b})
  end
```

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer: depends on the operation.  What's in your `for` loop?

Comment: No idea what you are asking for. Do you want to iterate over every element in a matrix?

Comment: I am storing the non zero elements in another matrix; with elements like the index number, value, row number and column number.

Comment: typically the code would look like:
for i=1:a
for j=1:b
body
end
end
my question is can i use one for statement instead of using two.

Comment: I suppose there are some ways around using multiple loops, the main question is what you want to achieve by it. If you simply want less lines you can put two `for` commands on a line seperated by a comma. The same holds for two `end` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, but one thing to consider is that in MATLAB you can often take advantage of linear indexing (instead of subscripting), without actually having to `reshape` the array.  For example,

```
>> A = [ 0   0   0   5
         0   2   0   0
         1   3   0   0
         0   0   4   0];
>> A(3,2)
ans =
     3
>> A(7) % A(3+(2-1)*size(A,1))
ans =
     3
```

You can often use this to your advantage in a `for` loop over all the elements:

```
for ii=1:numel(A),
   A(ii) = A(ii) + 1; % or something more useful
end
```

Is the same as:

```
for ii=1:size(A,2),
    for jj=1:size(A,1),
        A(jj,ii) = A(jj,ii) + 1;
    end
end
```

But to address your specific goal in this problem, as you stated in the comments ("I am storing the non zero elements in another matrix; with elements like the index number, value, row number and column number."), of making sparse matrix representation, it comes to this:

```
>> [i,j,s] = find(A);
>> [m,n] = size(A);
>> S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n)
S =
   (3,1)        1
   (2,2)        2
   (3,2)        3
   (4,3)        4
   (1,4)        5
```

But that's not really relevant to the broader question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can combine multiple loops into one `for`, however it would require you to loop over a vector containing all elements rather than the individual elements.

Here is a way to do it:

```
iRange = 1:2;
jRange = 1:3;
[iL jL] = ndgrid(iRange,jRange);
ijRange = [iL(:) jL(:)]';
for ij = ijRange
    i = ij(1); j = ij(2);
end
```

Note that looping over the variables may be simpler, but perhaps this method has some advantages as well.

Answer (score -1):

No

read this http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html
i also don't see any added value even if it was possible

Answer (score -1):

No I don't think you can put two for loops in one line.

Depends on your operation, you may be able to reshape it and use one for loop. If you are doing something as simple as just printing out all elements,

```
B = reshape(A,a*b,1);
for i=1:a*b
    c = B(i);
    ...
end
```